# Add a custom function to a model to retreive specific data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm building an app to evaluate children in a nursery school. (my wife is a nursery school teacher). This are the basic models and relations:

```
class Subevaluation extends Model
{
    // fields: id, title, date, classroom, course_id
    public function subevaluations(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Subevaluation');
    }
}

class Evaluation extends Model
{
    // fields: id, child_id, evaluation_id, quotation
    public function evaluation(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Evaluation');
    }
}
```

There are more models in my app (Child, Classroom,...) but the above 2 are the important ones for this issue.

Now I can retrieve all subevaluations of one selected evaluation; for example:

```
$eval = App\Evaluation::find(1);

$subevals = $eval->subevaluations;
```

And in my view I can list all the subevaluations:

```
@foreach($eval->subevaluations as $subeval)

  <td> {{ $subeval->student->name }}</td>
  <td> {{ $subeval->date }}</td>
  <td> {{ $subeval->quotation }}</td>

@endforeach
```

Here comes my question: (drumrolls...)

I want to be able to list the last 5 quotations made for this specific evaluation/course. So, in the @foreach loop, I want some kind of function like {{ $subeval->last5quotations }} that returns an array like this:

```
array{
  {
    'quot' => 'A',
    'date' => '2017-03-01',
    'info' => 'info here'
  },
  {
    'quot' => 'C',
    'date' => '2017-02-14',
    'info' => 'info here'
  },
  {
    'quot' => 'A',
    'date' => '2017-01-30',
    'info' => 'info here'
  },
  {
    'quot' => 'B',
    'date' => '2016-12-04',
    'info' => 'info here'
  },
  {
    'quot' => 'A',
    'date' => '2016-11-20',
    'info' => 'info here'
  }
}
```

This array (or can be collection) has the last 5 quotations given to each child - course

Then I can loop this array an show this info in the view

How can I achieve this in Laravel? (version 5.4)

Thank you!

Comment: How you get **`last5evals`** where is the relation or logic put your code here

Comment: I Don't have that function yet, it's just a suggestion... I still need a function like that

Comment: So you first find the **`evalutions`** then calls **`subevaluations`** though I don't see any relations in **`Evaluation`** model. Is **`last5evals`** is last five evaluations for your **`Subevaluation`**

Comment: Just changed the question, I used the wrong name. I hope the question is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your example, you could achieve this by:

```
class Evaluation extends Model
{
    public function subevaluations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subevaluation::class);
    }
}

$eval = App\Evaluation::find(1);
$last5subevals = $eval->subevaluations()->latest('date')->limit(5);
```

The function `latest($column = 'created_at')` Adds an "order by" clause for a timestamp to the query. And `limit($value)` should be self-explanatory (adds `LIMIT 5` to the SQL query created by those functions).

Here is more information about this on Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Answer (score 0):

You can add query constraints directly to the relation.

```
$subevals = $eval->subevaluations()->latest('date')->take(5);
```

Note that I'm calling the relationship as a method instead of a property. Also the `latest()` scope will order by `date` and `take(5)` is the equivalent to the SQL `LIMIT 5`.

Comment: So, I can make a new relationship like this?
`public function last5evals(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Subevaluation')->latest('date')->take(5);
}`

Comment: @JohnWings for something as simple as this you probably don't need to add any new relationships. The ones you have defined will work just fine. You can just chain the methods like above.

Comment: @JohnWings just keep in mind that `$eval->subevaluations` (as a property) will automatically load all the sub evaluations and `$eval->subevaluations()` (as a method) will start a new query builder instance that you can chain more methods off of.

Comment: @JohnWings this relation will not work for eager loading because in eager loading the related data are called by where in method so you can't say it will take five for all for where has & lazy loading this relation will work perfectly. when using any solution you should check if it has a n + 1 problem only my suggestion

Comment: @jfadich I think I used the wrong name, I don't want the last 5 subevaluations but I want the last 5 **quotations**. So, in my view, **WITHIN** the foreach loop of every subeval, I want to run a Query that retrieves the records (quotation, date, info) from table subevaluations where the course is _{this course}_ and student is _{this student}_

Comment: @JohnWings Please update your question then and include those relations or at least the table structure. Doing something like that you will definitely want to use eager loading like ARIFMAHMUDRANA mentioned.